# AngularJS Changing <body> class using global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, global-variables

I just created a angularJS application.

Here is my **index.html**

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">
  <head>
    <!-- CSS files import -->
  </head>
  <body class="{{bodylayout}}">
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
  <--! JS imports 
   aungular.js
   app.js
   login.js
   register.js
   -->
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';
//Define Routing for app
angular.module('myApp', []).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    })
    .when('/register', {
        templateUrl: 'register.html',
        controller: 'RegisterController'
      })
    .when('/forgotPassword', {
        templateUrl: 'forgotpassword.html',
        controller: 'forgotController'
      })
   .when('/home', {
       templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
    })
    .otherwise({
       redirectTo: '/login'
    });
//    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); //Remove the '#' from URL.
}]);
```

I have login.html, register.html, and forgotpassword.html, home.html. Each one has separate Controlers in separate files. login.js, register.js, forgot.js, home.js.

**login.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp').controller('LoginController', function($scope, $location, $window) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.loginUser=function()
    {
        var username=$scope.user.name;
        var password=$scope.user.password;
        if(username=="admin" && password=="admin123")
        {
            $location.path( "/home" );  
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.message="Error";
            $scope.messagecolor="alert alert-danger";
        }
    }
});
```

Similarly, I have post methods in other controllers.

What I want is, when the view is login or register or forgotpassword, the body class should be `"login-layout"`. So in body I put `class="{{bodylayout}}`". I know using global variables, the value can be set. But I don't know how to.

In **app.js** I tried this

```
angular.module('myApp').factory("myService", function(){

      return {
        sharedObject: { data: 'login-layout' }
      }; 

    });
```

But don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can create global variables in two way

- [$rootScope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope) //already mentioned @imcg
- [service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services)

Using `$rootScope` you can do something like in your `LoginController` controller

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('LoginController', function($scope, $location, $window, $rootScope) {
   $scope.user = {};
   $rootScope.bodylayout = 'login-layout';

   //others code 
}
```

Using `service`

```
angular.module('myApp').factory("myService", function(){

      return {
        sharedObject: { data: 'login-layout' }
      }; 

});
```

Use this service in your controller

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('LoginController', function($scope, $location, $window, myService) {
       $scope.user = {};
       $rootScope.bodylayout = myService.sharedObject.data; // get data from service

       //others code 
    }
```

Where your `HTML` looks like

```
<body class="{{bodylayout}}">
```

**Note** in this case you need to set `bodylayout` in each controller otherwise it use the old value

Comment: Thank. How to set other or blank if its other controller?

Comment: In other controller you can set `$rootScope.bodylayout = '' or $rootScope.bodylayout = 'other value' `

Comment: With service, how? Because we are using
`$rootScope.bodylayout = myService.sharedObject.data;` Not passing any value from controller.
And also I would like to change the title of page in each Controller.

Comment: Set different value in your service like `sharedObject: { data: 'login-layout', data2: 'another-layout' }` then in another controler use like `$rootScope.bodylayout = myService.sharedObject.data2`

Comment: From Controller we cannot set? In service create a mothod and pass value from controller?

Answer (score 11):

Try using the $rootScope:

```
$rootScope.bodyClass = 'login-layout';

<body class="{{$root.bodyClass}}">
```

You could handle this in the individual controllers, or perhaps in your app.js by listening for routeChangeSuccess:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, currentRoute) {
    switch(currentRoute.templateUrl) {
        case 'login.html':
        case 'register.html':
        case 'forgotpassword.html':
            $rootScope.bodyClass = 'login-layout';
            break;
        default:
            $rootScope.bodyClass = '';
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Use where? In which js file?

Comment: Much more clean solution, thanks! Although I would still go for using a service

Comment: since this is in the `$rootScope` you could simply use `<body class="{{bodyClass}}">` to reference it in your view.

Answer (score 8):

You could create a `<body>` directive that has add and remove class events that can be triggered throughout your app.

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('body', [function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$on('body:class:add', function(e, name){
        element.addClass(name);
      };
      scope.$on('body:class:remove', function(e, name){
        element.removeClass(name);
      };
      return;
    }
  };
}]);
```

In your `app.js` `config` block you can set the `<body>` `class` to whatever you want with `$emit`

```
## Add class
$rootScope.$emit('body:class:add', 'login-layout')

## Remove class
$rootScope.$emit('body:class:remove', 'login-layout')
```

it just simply uses the angular jqLite `addClass()` and `removeClass()` and also doesn't require you to tap into `$element` by using the directive `link` function which already has dom access to the element.

Even without `$rootScope` you can call it within your controllers with `$scope.$emit('body:class:add', name)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure the suggested answers work for Angular 1.4x but I think I have an easier solution.

You could easily add an activeTab property to your routes like this:

```
.when('/register', {
        templateUrl: 'register.html',
        controller: 'RegisterController',
        activeTab: 'register'
      })
```

Then in your Controller add the $route object to your $scope:

```
.controller('RegisterController', ['$scope', '$route', function($scope, $route){
     $scope.$route = $route;
}])
```

And use ng-class on your body tag:

```
<body ng-class="{'register-class' : $route.current.activeTab == 'register' }">
</body>
```

This way you can dynamically set a class on your body tag when you change routes. Hope this helps someone!