# How to switch <body> tags with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an HTML template with some classes in the `<body>` tag per screen. Like this login screen:

```
<body class="login-screen doABC doXZY etc">...
```

And this signup screen:

```
<body class="signup-screen doQWE doQAZ etc">...
```

**What is the best way to switch through these screens using Angular** and considering that I can't create containers like:

```
<body>
  <div class="login-screen doABC doXZY etc" ng-If="app1">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="signup-screen doQWE doQAZ etc" ng-If="app2">
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

Because the classes need to be in the `<body>` tag to work and refactoring everything would be extremely time-consuming. Note that these  classes trigger both CSS and JS functions.

Comment: You can [change<body> class using global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943820/angularjs-changing-body-class-using-global-variable)

Comment: You can [change <body> class using global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943820/angularjs-changing-body-class-using-global-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-style or ng-class to apply classes using angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to evaluate based on `scope.app1` value. General html `class` precedence rules still apply here. `doABC` then `doXZY` etc...

html

```
<body class="doABC doXZY etc" ng-class="screenBasedClass()"></body>
```

script

```
$scope.screenBasedClass = function () {
    if ($scope.app1) {
        return 'login-screen'
    } else if ($scope.app2) {
        return 'signup-screen';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-class` feature.

- Keep `ng-app` in `html` tag and root level control `appCtrl` also in `html`
- Keep a scope value in root control `appCtrl` and whenever you switch screen, change class name.

#### html

```
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
<head>
</head>
<body class="doABC doXZY etc" ng-class="bodyClass">
    <!-- body content or routing div -->
</body>
</html>
```

#### javascript

```
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.bodyClass = '';

    $scope.changeBodyClass(className) {
        $scope.bodyClass = className
    }
})
```

Whenever you want to change class, you can change class by `changeBodyClass` method. You can also put a `$broadcast` listener and change class from outside.